# Flutter GetX issue in get: ^4.6.1

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetX very first time in my flutter project. here is my simple code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: "Snackbar",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('SnackBar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.snackbar('Test title', 'test Body');
                },
                child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I am trying to run the App it shows bellow  error

```
/C:/Users/wmpkw/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_cupertino_app.dart:252:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
            useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/app.dart:145:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const CupertinoApp({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/wmpkw/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:275:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
                useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,

                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:217:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const MaterialApp.router({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/wmpkw/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:322:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
                useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:166:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const MaterialApp({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

this is the dependencies on my pubspec.yaml

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

## The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
get: ^4.6.1

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: 1. share your pubspec.yaml file  
2. delete dart_tools and flutter pub get again

Answer (score 0):

try `flutter upgrade` and then `flutter pub get`.
Hope you get the solution!

Answer (score 0):

if you are building your project without null safety then instead of using "get: ^4.6.1" use "get: ^3.26.0" in your pubspec.yaml file